# Problem on set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbb R$ be set of real numbers and $A, B, C$ be subset of $\mathbb R$. Consider the set $C=\{x \in \mathbb R: x\in A \implies x\in B\}$. Can you someone elaborate this definition.
(1) If $x\in A$ only then it lies in $C$ or not?
(2) If $x\in B$ only then it lies in $C$ or not?
(3) which type of element $C$ have?

Comment: that means x lies in C if x lies in A intersection B

Comment: What is the origin of the problem? Since it seems rather unusual to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would say: Rewrite $(x\in A \implies x\in B)$ as $(x\notin A \lor x\in B)$. Then you see that $C=B\cup A^c$. In other words, $C$ contains all elements that are in $B$ plus those that are not in $A$.

That $\alpha\implies \beta$ is equivalent to $\lnot \alpha \lor \beta$ is a useful fact that is used in proofs by contradiction. I.e. to prove $\alpha\implies \beta$, mathematicians often say "Suppose to the contrary ..." where the contrary is $\lnot(\alpha\implies\beta)$, that is, by the given equivalence, $(\alpha\land \lnot \beta)$.

Comment: I am not fully agree with this. Can you provide me three sets A, B and C which can explain this thing.

Comment: The definition of $(x\in A\implies x\in B)$ is $(x\notin A\lor x\in B)$. For example, take $A=$ even numbers, $B=$ odd numbers. Then $C=B$ since no odd number satisfies $x\in A$.

Comment: I put my question in different way Let A is the collection of convergent sequence and B is the collection of cauchy sequence then what will be C ?

Comment: It will be $B\cup A^c$, where $A^c$ is the set of all sequences that are not convergent. But instead of looking for examples, it suffices to look at the definition of $\implies$. Note that by $\cup$ I mean "union", so $B\cup A^c=\{z| z\in B\lor z\in A^c\}$

Comment: To make a more specific example, take $A=\{x|x>100\}$, $B=\{x| x  \text{ is prime}\}$, then $C$ is the prime numbers plus all real numbers smaller or equal to 100.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking what are the elements of set $\;\{x \in \mathbb R: x\in A \implies x\in B\}\;$.  Why not just calculate?

\begin{align}
& x \in \{x \in \mathbb R: x\in A \implies x\in B\} \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of the set builder notation"} \\
& x \in \mathbb R \;\land\; (x \in A \implies x \in B) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: write $\;P \implies Q\;$ as $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$"} \\
& x \in \mathbb R \;\land\; (x \not\in A \lor x \in B) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: distribute $\;\land\;$ over $\;\lor\;$"} \\
& (x \in \mathbb R \land x \not\in A) \;\lor\; (x \in \mathbb R \land x \in B) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$; we are given that $\;B \subseteq \mathbb R\;$"} \\
& x \in \mathbb R \setminus A \;\lor\; x \in B \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cup\;$"} \\
& x \in (\mathbb R \setminus A) \cup B \\
\end{align}
So this set $\;C\;$ is the union of the complement of $\;A\;$ with $\;B\;$.

Another way to write this set is $\;A^c \cup B\;$, but note that $\;^c\;$ always refers to an implicit universe, which in this case is $\;\mathbb R\;$.